# Как подключить stm32f103c6 в Proteus правильно

Tags: stm32, proteus, stm32cubeide

Создал проект в Proteus, добавил в него из доступных кристаллов stm32 f103c6. Написал прошивку для f103c6 в STM32CubeIDE, код простой- мигание портом gpio b13.
Хочу к этой ноге подключить транзистор биполярный bd139, но в Proteus ток слишком маленький, около 6 нано ампер и транзистор не открывается, хотя по даташиту ток должен быть приличный.

С ардуиной все было просто, а тут танцы с бубнами.

Почему ток такой маленький?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Proteus при симуляции STM32 микроконтроллеров действительно есть небольшая "особенность", выходной ток GPIO-выходов слишком мал для управления аналоговыми элементами.

Есть два выхода:

Выход первый "просто помигать светодиодом":
Переключаем режим симуляции светодиода на "цифровой" и подключаем его напрямую к GPIO(либо через резистор, номинал которого не влияет на результат).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выход второй, если нужно управлять аналоговой нагрузкой:
Ищем в библиотеке раздел "Simulator Primitives" элемент "AND" или "OR" и ставим его как буферный элемент сразу после GPIO. Таким образом выходной ток усилится при моделировании, что позволит нам управлять аналоговой нагрузкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]